# Close multiple popup windows using only one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a small problem.
I am making a website that, when a button is pressed, creates 2 popup windows. One shows one image and the other shows a bunch of controls, including two buttons. I want the buttons to close both popups at the same time.

I've tried to attribute the window to a variable, but then, upon trying to close it, I'm shown "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined", but the variable is defined.

This is making me go out of my mind, and it's probably something quite simple.
Can anyone help, please?

EDIT: A very basic form of the code is here:

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>

<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tbd7k511/1/

Comment: please show some "relevant" code

Comment: Not knowing what you are doing, without seeing the code, we can only guess..

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
myWindow2.close();
```

in your

```
closeWin()
```

**Javascript**

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>

<script>
  var myWindow;
  var MyWindow2;

  function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow2 = window.open("", "myWindow2", "width=200,height=200");
  }

  function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
    myWindow2.close();
  }

</script>
<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>
```